# Is the reaction of anhydrous aluminium(III) chloride and anhydrous ethanol reversible?

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, stability

I'm planning an experiment that I'll do *in silico* in the near future, and one of the steps involves the extraction of the $\ce{AlCl3 · C2H5OH}$ adduct without any water in it.

Can the ethanol be simply boiled off to obtain anhydrous aluminum chloride, or does it end up as, say, a mixture of ethyl chloride and aluminum hydroxide or something?

Comment: You can buy solutions of Aluminium Chloride in Ethanol so it is reasonably stable. this suggests that the EtOH can be evaporated off to give you back the AlCl3

Comment: I'm just doing it in silico, partly since I'm not an adult yet (an 18 year old is still a minor where I live) and therefore might not be able to buy official reagents, and partly since I don't have physical equipment. 